# Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, .net

Unknown build error,

> Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it has not
>   been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent
>   assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the
>   ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting an error Cannot resolve dependency to assembly System.Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681599/getting-an-error-cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-system-web)

Comment: Also a detailed answer on Microsoft's forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/452dae83-edac-4932-93c7-efaafe20cd92/getting-an-error-cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-systemweb?forum=msbuild)