# How to resolve assembly dependency of system.web in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, dll

I have a WPF application source code when I am trying to open it in visual studio 2017 then it's giving error like 
`Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'`

I have search for related links but it's not resolve issue. Please can you help me to resolve this issue ?

Link which I get for resolve the issue is [Getting an error Cannot resolve dependency to assembly System.Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681599/getting-an-error-cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-system-web)

Comment: I Think this link could help you to resolve your struggle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681599/getting-an-error-cannot-resolve-dependency-to-assembly-system-web

Comment: I have check it but it didn't resolve issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check .chproj file of directory and remove system reference. And after that you should add reference manually System and system.web which required for your application. Error clearly indicating for dependency to assembly so please check and add required assembly from reference.